# How to add datetime and time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

In my database table, I am storing current date and time using `NOW()` function. The column type is `DATETIME` and it is storing in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

I am trying to write a query that selects the date and time from my table column and adding HH:MM to retrieved date and time like

```
SELECT date FROM tablename by adding fetched date which is (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) + HH:MM
```

The above query is just to make you know what I was trying.

Actually I don't know how to add date and time in mysql while retrieving the data.

How can we add `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` and `HH:MM` while retrieving the data in mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ADDTIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) in MySQL:

```
SELECT ADDTIME('2016-07-15 18:00:00', '02:30');
```

or with [`DATEADD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2016-07-15 18:00:00', INTERVAL '02:30' HOUR_MINUTE);
```

Both Result as:

```
2016-07-15 20:30:00
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't do anything special:

```
SELECT ... WHERE datetimefield = '2016-07-15 13:13:00'
```

mysql will parse the string to see if it looks like a valid date/datetime value and convert it for you automatically.

For date "math", you can do that directly as well:

```
mysql> select '2016-07-16 13:13:00' + INTERVAL 3 hour + INTERVAL 15 minute;
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| '2016-07-16 13:13:00' + INTERVAL 3 hour + INTERVAL 15 minute |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2016-07-16 16:28:00                                          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```